# cannot get single new line \n

Tags: c#, string, email

I'm trying to create 2 lists of items in an email body by passing in a string upon creation. One of the lists works perfectly with no problems (I.E. each entry is on a new line, just as intended), but I cannot figure out how to get the other list formatted in the same way. It's either no new lines, or double line spacing. I've tried the System.environment.newline, "\r\n", '\n', "\n", etc. When I set a breakpoint in the code, the string has the '\n' in the appropriate places, but it's not showing up when the email is created. Any tips?

```
string users = "";
for (int i = 0; i < disabledUsers.Count; i++)
{
    users += disabledUsers[i] + "\n"; //This does not show up as a new line for each item in an email
}

// initializing users with expired passwords to a string format
string expiredUserPasswords = "";
for (int i = 0; i < expiredPassword.Count; i++)
{
    expiredUserPasswords += expiredPassword[i] + "\n"; //this works perfectly
}

// creating admin message
MailMessage emailAdmin = new MailMessage();
emailAdmin.From = new MailAddress("email.email@email.com");
emailAdmin.Body = "Automated system message:\n\nThe following " + numExpiredPasswords + " accounts have expired passwords and have been disabled:\n\n" + expiredUserPasswords + "\n\nThe following " + numDisabledAccounts + " accounts have been disabled for 90+ days:\n\n" + users + "\n\nThere are " + activeNum + " active users, " + numDisabled + " disabled users, and " + totalNum + " total users.\n\nThis is an automatically generated email. Please do not reply.";
emailAdmin.Subject = "Dataroom cleanup log";
```

I can't see ahy difference between these two lists and why one works fine while the other one won't. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit - I figured it out. Thanks to Microbloft, Outlook automatically removes what it thinks are excessive newline commands. I fixed it by just adding a period right before the newline, so ".\n".

Comment: Have you try Stringbuilder? edit

Comment: @butterbox That won't fix his current problem.

Comment: @kcducttaper: Please post your solution not as an edit, but as an answer, and then accept an answer (as soon as you're allowed to), so that the question will show up as resolved.

Comment: So stringbuilder solved the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Thanks to Microbloft, Outlook automatically removes what it thinks are excessive newline commands. I fixed it by just adding a period right before the newline, so:

```
    users += disabledUsers[i] + ".\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
for (int i = 0; i < disabledUsers.Count; i++)
{
    users += disabledUsers[i] + "\n";
}
```

Use the much shorter

```
var users = string.Join("\n", disabledUsers);
```

You can do the same with the expired passwords, of course.

If for some reason it does not solve your problem, just use Html in the body of your email and separate with a `<br />` tag instead.

Answer (score 1):

I would enable the HTML body and then use `<br />` instead. Often email services are sketchy with your way for some reason. However I have never had a problem using Environment.Newline();

```
 emailAdmin.IsBodyHtml = true;

 for (int i = 0; i < disabledUsers.Count; i++)
 {
      users += disabledUsers[i] + "<br />"; //This now works
 }
```

This way simply enables a linebreak using html.

Also you may want to add two rather than one, but this just depends on personal preference to you.

**OR**

For the way the OP has answered his own question you could do this instead:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < disabledUsers.Count; i++)
 {
      users += disabledUsers[i] + ".\n"; //This now works
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

for a new line on on-Unix platforms you use: `"\r\n"` and on Unix platforms you use `"\n"`, but you could use `Environment.NewLine` and it will decide for you.